# Batch update VS batch insert and update with join

Tags: sql-server

I have a case where I need to update 10-50k entries in a very large table. The table is like this.

```
int id PK
varchar username
boolean active
int category
and other random columns
```

There is an index on username and category. I have to update say 20k records for category 1. We have maybe 500k more on other categories that are not being touched.

We use spring jdbc on the jtds driver still with SQL Server. The question is which approach do we think would be faster.

1. Batch update looping on a list of usernames with something like:

`update table set active = 1 where username = ? and category = 1`

2. Batch inserts into temp table, then update with a join:

`insert into #temp values ?`

then one big: `update table set active = 1 from #temp join table on #temp.username = table.username and category = 1`

Any guesses as to which approach would be faster in general? I can run tests for me, but this goes out to others, some have faster DB, some slower, some across a network, some faster.

Comment: Just run the direct update. The index seek yields PKs into the main table. I see no advantage to using a temp table as an intermediate step. SQL server should be able to update 20k rows without any issues. Just setting a BIT value shouldn't even require any page splits or reorganizations. You might see a spike in transaction log size though.

Comment: You lost me at `We use spring jdbc on the jtds driver still with SQL Server.` Why would anyone use the old jtds driver, unless you're working with really sql server versions and don't want to support any newer features that come out in the last 10 years or so

Comment: WIth that being said, i'd probably go for #2

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. FYI, in our test server, the insert to temp table then one big update was 20% or so faster when using a preparedstatement batch insert/update size of 1k records. The initial table has indexes on the active column and lots of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an efficient way to get all the usernames into SQL, I would go that route and updating everything at once. While there's not that much overhead on a single update statement, over the course of 20k updates, those are going to add up. Plus, the operation is not atomic if you do them one at a time which may or may not be a problem if one fails halfway through.

One option you could do is just pass in all the usernames as json (or xml, or even a delimited string) then unpack the values and update rows where the username is one of the unpacked values. Personally, I'd go with JSON as it's the most succinct and safe from problems arising from delimiters.

Here are some examples of how you could accomplish that in SQL. All of these assume you format some sort of serialized string of usernames.

**Using JSON:**

```
declare 
    @UsernamesJSON nvarchar(max) = N'[ "alice", "bob", "charlie" ]',
    @Category int = 1

update t
set Active = 1
from MyTable t
inner join openjson(@UsernamesJSON) s
    on t.Username = s.Value
where t.Category = @Category
```

**Using a Delimited String**

```
-- These are your input parameters from your app
declare 
    @Usernames nvarchar(max) = N'Alice|Bob|Charlie|Deborah|Eggbert',
    @Category int = 1

update t
set Active = 1
from MyTable t
inner join string_split(@UserNames, '|') s
    on t.Username = s.Value
where Category = @Category
```

**Using XML**

```
declare @UsernamesXML xml = N'
<names>
    <name>alice</name>
    <name>bob</name>
    <name>charlie</name>
</names>
'

update t
set Active = 1
from MyTable t
inner join @UsernamesXML.nodes('names/name') as a(c)
    on t.username = a.c.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
where Category = @Category
```

Comment: we just ended up using batch insert instead of passing all in at once. batch inserts were still very quick.